# Select elements in the dom only if they have the attribute disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to get elements from the Dom only disabled "disabled =" disabled "", then apply a value using angularjs, for this I'm using "getElementsByTagName", what happens is that I do not know how to select only those with the attribute disabled.
I'm trying to apply it in a custom directive:

HTML:

```
                <deb-button 
                base-path="assets\assets-angular" 
                textbtn="Primary" 
                colorbtn="primary"
                disabled="disabled">
                </deb-button>
```

JS

```
.directive('debButton', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  templateUrl: function (element, attrs) {
    return attrs.basePath + "/templates/debbutton.html";
  },
  scope: {
    textbtn: '@',
    colorbtn: '@',
    isdisabled: '@'
  },
  controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName('deb-button');
    if (b) {
      console.log(b);
    }      
  }],
  link: function ($scope, colorbtn, isdisabled) {
    if (!$scope.colorbtn) {
      $scope.colorbtn = 'primary';
    }
  }
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Other buttons not the current one? Or only the current one? Also do they all reside within one controller instance?

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using `querySelector` rather than `getElementsByTag` which allows you to write CSS style selectors for example.

If you just want to get all the disabled deb-buttons you can do so like so

```
var b = document.querySelectorAll('deb-button:disabled')
```

But if you want to get all the elements that have the `disabled` attribute value set to `disabled`

```
var b = document.querySelectorAll('deb-button[disabled="disabled"]');
```

But if you want to use getElementsByTagName you could loop over the result of `getElementsByTagName` and filter the deb-buttons that don't have the disabled attribute

ES6:

```
var b = document.getElementsByTagName('deb-button').filter( e => e.getAttribute('disabled') === 'disabled' )
```

ES5:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('deb-button');
var b = [];
for (var i= 0; i < a.length; i++){
   if (a[i].getAttribute('disabled') === 'disabled') { b.push(a[i]) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you are using directive i will prefer to use the selector this way:

> function link(scope, element, attr) {
>   angular.element(element.querySelectorAll('deb-button:disabled') 
>   }

It's just another way of doing it.